# Random array update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array in which two values are compared in a random order. How do i update the values? Help, if not hard.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = [{
      "q1": "a",
      "an": "a"
    }, {
      "q1": "b",
      "an": "b"
    }, {
      "q1": "c",
      "an": "c"
    }];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var answer = $("#answer").val();
      if (answer == myArray[rand].an) {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "OK!" + "</div>");
      } else {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "NO!" + "</div>");
      }
      $("#answer").val('');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <input id="answer" />
    <div id="comment"></div>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: _"How do i update the values?"_ what do mean by "update the values"? Do you want to go to the next question?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I do not know English well.

Comment: only next. or any other randomly ??

Comment: **copy/paste** `var rand = ......` and `$("#question").html........` lines inside the click .. After `$("#answer").val('');` .. In this case remove `var` from before `rand`

Comment: any other randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <input id="answer" />
    <div id="comment"></div>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = [{
      "q1": "a",
      "an": "a"
    }, {
      "q1": "b",
      "an": "b"
    }, {
      "q1": "c",
      "an": "c"
    }];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var answer = $("#answer").val();
      if (answer == myArray[rand].an) {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "OK!" + "</div>");
      } else {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "NO!" + "</div>");
      }
      $("#answer").val('');
    });
  $("#next").click(function(){

   var newRand =rand;
   while(rand==newRand)
   {
     newRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
   }
rand =newRand;
    $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[newRand].q1 + "</div>");
  });
});
```

Here is the Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/eax8cvwn/

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, this does not work. The next value is an error.

Comment: After I click the "Next" button and enter a new value in the input, I get an error when comparing.

Comment: Okay. Got It. just Updating

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array values like this:

```
myArray[0].an = 'new value';
```

Where `0` is the "row" in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your random value after button click. So put below line inside button click.

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
$("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArray = [{
    "q1": "a",
    "an": "a"
  }, {
    "q1": "b",
    "an": "b"
  }, 
  {
    "q1": "c",
    "an": "c"
  },
  {
    "q1": "d",
    "an": "d"
  },
  {
    "q1": "e",
    "an": "e"
  }];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var answer = $("#answer").val();
    if (answer == myArray[rand].an) {
      $("#comment").html("<div>" + "OK!" + "</div>");
    } else {
      $("#comment").html("<div>" + "NO!" + "</div>");
    }
    $("#answer").val('');
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <input id="answer" />
  <div id="comment"></div>
  <button id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

push the newly generated random number into a array and check if it exists using `indexOf` and generate new random number. and check if all questions answered using question's array length and random number array length and complete the quiz.

Try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = [{
      "q1": "a",
      "an": "a"
    }, {
      "q1": "b",
      "an": "b"
    }, {
      "q1": "c",
      "an": "c"
    }];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
    var askedQtn = [];
    askedQtn.push(rand);
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var answer = $("#answer").val();
      if (answer == myArray[rand].an) {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "OK!" + "</div>");
      } else {
        $("#comment").html("<div>" + "NO!" + "</div>");
      }
      $("#answer").val('');
      var newRand =rand;
      if(myArray.length <= askedQtn.length){
        $("#wrap").html("<div id='text'>Questions Over</div>");
      } else {
        while(askedQtn.indexOf(rand) >= 0)
        {
          rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        }
        askedQtn.push(rand);
        $("#question").html("<div id='text'>" + myArray[rand].q1 + "</div>");
       }
     
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <input id="answer" />
    <div id="comment"></div>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
```